# Перенос проектов из Microsoft Visual Studio в Embarcadero RAD Studio

Tags: visual-studio, embarcadero, импорт

Как я понимаю функций прямого импорта между MSVS и RAD Studio не имеется. Соответственно вопрос: а существует ли вообще какой-то способ, возможно сторонний софт, для быстрого переноса проектов (или даже целых решений .sln) из Microsoft Visual Studio в Embarcadero RAD Studio (c++ builder)? Всем известные copy/paste в расчет не берем.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, возможность быстрой миграции из MSVS в RAD Studio отсутствует. Это не просто разные IDE. Они используют разные библиотеки с разной архитектурой.

Код, который использует только стандартные библиотеки С++ и WinAPI, возможно, ещё удастся относительно безболезненно перенести. Остальное придётся переписывать и/или адаптировать.